# What is the true meaning of "but" in this context? Does it mean "except"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

what is the true meaning of "but" in this context? does it means "except"?

> From all that I was able to observe in the presence of Mrs. Jencken, I
>   am forced to come to the conclusion that the phenomena peculiar to
>   that medium are of a strongly objective and convincing nature, and
>   they would, I think, be sufficient for **the most pronounced but Honest**
>   sceptic to cause him to reject ventriloquism, muscular action, and
>   every such artificial explanation of the phenomena.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's ordinary "but".

"Somebody who is the most pronounced sceptic, but also the most honest sceptic".